# Reading inpustream

Tags: java, android, io, bluetooth

i am trying to send integers to Android device via Bluetooth communication. My question is how do i read array of charcters from the inpustream?

This is a partion of my server code Java:

```
try {
    outStream = connection.openOutputStream();  
    int numbers = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    outStream.write(numbers);
    System.out.println(numbers);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The objective is to Android reads the integers that the server sends. I have also tryd to use PrintWriter method to send data(randome numbers) like this:

```
outStream = connection.openOutputStream();
pWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outStream));

int numbers = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
pWriter.write(numbers);
System.out.println(numbers);
pWriter.flush();
pWriter.close();
```

if use this method print.write, i know that this it send only single charchters, so my question is how do i send array of charchters to Android?

this the portion of my Android code:

```
public void run() {
    int data = in.read(buffer);

    while (true) {
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int data;

            data = in.read(buffer);
            data = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG_IOThread, "disconnected", ex);
            break;
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: This `outStream.write(numbers)` writes a byte, not an integer. Wrap both ends with a `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream` instead.

Comment: i have changed on the server side like this: `outStream = connection.openDataOutputStream(); int numbers = (int) (Math.random() * 10); outStream.write(numbers);`

but on Android when i change DataInput i get option to use method like
`data = in.readInt();` But how do i add buffer in it?

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed the DataOutpustream, i used writeInt() method and on the server i changed to readInt(); I thought it was posibble to use OutputStream to send integers and InputStream to receive it.